# exp function run time comparison ifort vs gfortran

Tags: performance, assembly, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I wrote this code:

```
program exponent
    implicit none

    real(8) :: sum
    integer(8) :: i
    integer :: limit
    real :: start, end

    sum = 0d0
    limit = 10000000
    call CPU_TIME(start)
    do i=1, limit
        sum = sum + exp(i*1.d0/limit)
    end do
    call CPU_TIME(end)
    print *, sum
    print '("Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',end-start
end program exponent
```

And I compiled it with gfortran 10.1.0 and ifort 19.1.3.304 on CentOS Linux 7 using:

`ifort *.f90 -O3 -o intel.out`

`gfortran *.f90 -O3 -o gnu.out`

and the outputs are:

gnu:

```
17182819.143730670
Time = 0.248 seconds.
```

intel:

```
17182819.1437313
Time = 0.051 seconds.
```

When I run a few times, the run time of each is pretty much the same.

Why is ifort faster than gfortran and how can I make gfortran run as fast as ifort?

Comment: This looks like a difference in the `exp` implementation. Intel might be already cutting some corners at `O3` while GCC uses GLIBC. However, try also running the tests in the opposite order. The test is too small to really let the CPU to fully spin up. Also, time just the loop.

Comment: I can confirm the difference. On a computer without CPU throttling it is quite enough to do one try. Multiple tries in a loop did not make a difference. `-ffast-math` makes gfortran marginally faster but not much.

Comment: Similalrly I get ifort about 2-3 times quicker, but the sum results for intel at -O3 are slightly different. This difference survives me carefully bracketing things to ensure the same order of evaluation. At -O1 for intel the results are the same, and the times much more similar (intel still slightly faster). this suggests ifort is cutting corners at -O3 for exp. Ouch. Metings now, will write answer latter

Comment: Interestingly ifx is much more similar to gfortran, both in times and "accuracy" of results

Comment: Like @VladimirF already said only time the loop, when using `time` you also record the time the OS needs to start / shutdown the application, loading libraries etc.. `time` is **not** usable for bench marking.

Comment: Should have added my times are from just timing the loop. And on second thought Intel might be vectorising or otherwise reordering the loop differently, rather than approximating exp

Comment: I edited the code so that I only time the loop. Ifort is still faster.

Comment: Might also be useful to add the versions of the used ifort and gfortran compilers and the OS you are using.

Comment: added compiler versions and OS to the question

Answer (score 5):

ifort is mainly faster because **it uses its own optimized math library called SVML** (provided with the Intel compiler). This library is often faster since it provides optimized *vectorized* primitives, even without `-ffastmath`. Moreover, the Intel compiler tends to better vectorize loops (especially with reduction like this).

You can see the difference [on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9MhqMcoK9): the ifort version vectorizes the loop by working on 2 numbers at a time while the gfortran version uses a slower scalar exponential.

Note that using `-mavx2` helps ifort to generate a faster code thanks to the AVX instruction set. Using AVX-512 instructions (if available on the target machine) could be even faster.
gfortran can vectorize the loop with `-march=native` on GodBolt (but strangely not with `-march=skylake` and `-ffast-math`).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I added `-no-vec` to ifort compilation and `-fno-tree-vectorize` to gfortran. The new timings are: ifort - 0.142 sec, gnu - 0.248 sec. So, indeed, vectorization took part in the run time difference, but ifort is still faster. Is there a way to make gfortran as fast as ifort?

Comment: Probably yes, by either linking the SVML in the gfortran version. I am not sure it is well supported. At least, it should be possible to use the SVML manually in the worst case. Alternatively, you can use the standard libmath installed in the ifort version although both versions will be slow in this case. Another solution is to write your own vectorized code but this is cumbersome to do (although they are good research paper for that).

Comment: gfortran will use the math function implemented in libm on your system.  You can replace `exp()` with a faster implementation.  Search for "P.T.P Tang  Table-driven" for one such method.

Comment: @steve There are significantly  faster implementation nowadays. The GNU implementation already use some optimized table-based algorithm, but state of the art algorithms (like the one use in SVML) outperform it (especially due to vectorization, but not only). Here is a reference of a quite new paper: "Fast Exponential Computation on SIMD Architectures" (2015).

Comment: *even without `-ffast-math`* - note that ICC's (and I assume ifort's) default is `-fp-model fast=1`.  Not quite as aggressive as `fp-model fast=2` but still more like `-ffast-math` in the ways that matter here.  e.g. it allows ifort to pretend that FP math is associative and vectorize sums of arrays, or in this case `addpd` on a pair of vectorized exp results instead of separately adding each element to a scalar sum *inside* the loop.

Comment: Strange that gfortran will only use vectorized `exp` with `-march=skylake-avx512` (native on those cloud server), not `-march=skylake`.  Even `-mveclibabi=svml` or `acml` doesn't help. https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec says gcc4.9 should be able to vectorize C functions like `cos()` with `-O1 -fopenmp -ffast-math -lm -mavx2`, or `-O1 -ftree-loop-vectorize -ffast-math -lm -mavx`.  (-O3 includes -ftree-vectorize)